# P-channel MOSFET stays on when the gate driver is unpowered

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I can't change bulb wiring so I used P-channel MOSFET to PWM bulbs. To save the space I used gate driver and in order to save battery life all ICs are powered from ignition (interruptible 12V). MOSFETs' source is powered from separated fused 12V line.

[image: Mosfet connection]

Driver's output stage is tied to the ground so I added pull-up resistor to the gate to keep it off when the driver is off.
[image]

The problem is MOSFET is fully on when the driver is powered off.
Vgs is -2.41V. Should I unsolder the driver - MOSFET is off.

When the driver is powered - everything works as expected
Can't get what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: That diode across the high-side NPN may be the culprit- combined with D2,D3 the pull - up on the FET gates will dribble current into V+ Of the driver chip when it’s not getting power from elsewhere.

Comment: But do you ever have power on +12V and not on IGN_KEY?

Comment: According to [the datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9310pbf.pdf), the irf9310 can have a threshold voltage as low as 1.3V. I do not like the fact that R4 is 10K, while the internal resistor of the driver is 100K. With a 12V supply, the drain through the driver will bring you close to that 1.3V. I would cut R4 approximately in half to 4.7K. The driver should be able to handle that.

Comment: @Frog yes, it is powered. I'm testing it on the table. I may consider removing turn-on diodes for the test purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem in detail, I think you should rework the circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZfeNZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
AC coupling might be the simple solution to this.

Comment: Would you explain it a bit? I'm almost desperate not able to find the root cause and ready to do it in a simple NPN-as-a-gate-driver way

Comment: Your circuit is backfeeding in DC. Once it is ac coupled, it will break this connection. I don't know what kind of signal you are feeding the circuit. But if it is pwm this will definitely work.  Another thing you can try, because the impedance is low on a power supply while off, is to put a diode in series with the Vcc of the predriver chip so that this low impedance is not exerting itself through the circuit. If the output device was reworked to be a n-channel enhancement mode mosfet, there wouldn't be much issues, as the negative loading effect would gate the mosfet off.

Answer (score 0):

> Vgs is -2.41V. Should I unsolder the driver - mosfet is off.

Cut R4 and R15 from 10K to 4.7K or even 2.2K. That will lower the absolute value of Vgs. According to [the datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9310pbf.pdf) the IRF9310 can have a threshold voltage as low as 1.3V. The [MC34141](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34151-d.pdf) should be able to handle the change in pull-up resistors.

Comment: Just tried 4k7. With 12V I measured -2.11V on the gate and it's still on. I'l try 2k2 later but looks like I have to do it trial and error way. But if I'm correct, R4/R15 is a voltage divider together with pull-down resistor of the driver. Then decreasing pull up resistor I will decrease voltage on the gate? And I checked several gate driver - is there some low-side drivers with pull up instead of pull down? May be it's a better approach.

Comment: I'm wondering if your ignition key is set up like a "kill switch". Instead of simply disconnecting the 12V, it actually _grounds_ that rail, (to prevent theft via "hot-wiring"). Yes, a different driver might make the necessary difference in your case.

Comment: Due to the negative drive, the pull up resistor is backfeeding the predriver circuit, because the Vcc side of the perdriver rail is acting like a low impedance load.